# Socket.io keeps timing out on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, socket.io

This is the following code of my app.js:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(port);

io.configure(function () {
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
    io.set("polling duration", 10);
});

var spaces = {};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/view.html');
});

app.get('/img/rocket.svg', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/img/rocket.svg');
});

app.get('/:spaceid', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/control.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('serve', function(data) {
    spaces[data.spaceId] = socket;
  });

  socket.on('control', function (data) {
    var spaceSocket = spaces[data.spaceId];
    if (spaceSocket) {
      spaceSocket.emit('control', data);
    }
  });

});
```

This is what I get when I do `heroku logs`

```
2013-05-17T18:18:06.873629+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2013-05-17T18:18:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: express.createServer() is deprecated, express
2013-05-17T18:18:08+00:00 app[web.1]: applications no longer inherit from http.Server,
2013-05-17T18:18:08+00:00 app[web.1]: please use:
2013-05-17T18:18:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-17T18:18:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   var express = require("express");
2013-05-17T18:18:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   var app = express();
2013-05-17T18:18:08+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-17T18:18:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Socket.IO's `listen()` method expects an `http.Server` instance
2013-05-17T18:18:09+00:00 app[web.1]: as its first parameter. Are you migrating from Express 2.x to 3.x?
2013-05-17T18:18:08.076300+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-17T18:18:09+00:00 app[web.1]: If so, check out the "Socket.IO compatibility" section at:
2013-05-17T18:18:09+00:00 app[web.1]: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x
2013-05-17T18:18:09+00:00 app[web.1]: info: socket.io started
2013-05-17T18:18:09.745293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H18 desc="Request Interrupted" method=GET path=/ host=myapp123.herokuapp.com fwd="80.47.193.237" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=0ms status=503 bytes=0 sock=client
2013-05-17T18:18:11.428152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H18 desc="Request Interrupted" method=GET path=/ host=myapp123.herokuapp.com fwd="80.47.193.237" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=0ms status=503 bytes=0 sock=client
```

I've researched that can't use WebSockets and have to configure it differently. I'm unsure if I have that correctly. Can anyone spot any mistakes in the code? Please bear in mind I'm learning this stuff at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is exactly what the error states. Use this instead:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer(app)
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(80);
```

The problem with your application is that `socket.io` is looking for an instance of `http.Server`, and Express changed its API when version 3 was released. Notice these errors:

```
Warning: express.createServer() is deprecated, express
applications no longer inherit from http.Server

Socket.IO's `listen()` method expects an `http.Server` instance
as its first parameter. Are you migrating from Express 2.x to 3.x?
```

Starting an app the way you showed originally did return an instance of `http.Server`, but that has since changed. [Here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x#changed) is a list of things changed from Express 2 to 3. Here's the straight quote:

> Keep in mind that the return value of express() is no longer an
>   http.Server instance.

The method was deprecated in [this](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commit/42fd29efe8c11cfb3485a872295448225afc1e89) commit. You also may find [this](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commit/7e81cad0bf253f5b673daa2d07d5378f8f77e15d#L4R524) commit of interest. Aside from that, websockets do indeed fail to work on Heroku, so your settings are correct.

Comment: Any luck finding a computer?

Comment: Updated answer. It was actually incorrect - I didn't bother to look at my own source.